# Perform action at the end of Observalbe life cycle

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

How can I do some final actions whenever the Observable is completed or aborted? Something similar to [jQuery Deferred .always()](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/) mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the `finally` method described here: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/finally.md

Comment: Thanks! It looks like documentation for .finally() is missed for RxJS5